# Spring boot with Java Faker throwing dependency error

Tags: spring-boot, faker

I am using Spring Boot and using `Java Faker` dependency. I am getting the below error. I am of opinion that spring boot works out of the box and should take of versions. Where am I going wrong?

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.classpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>orders-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>orders-api</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<!--            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>-->
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

```
docker container run -p 8222:8222 orders-api
11:23:01.726 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - Application failed to start due to an exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions.setMaxAliasesForCollections(int)'
        at org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader.createYaml(OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:69)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:164)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader.load(OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:84)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLoader.load(StandardConfigDataLoader.java:54)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLoader.load(StandardConfigDataLoader.java:36)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLoaders.load(ConfigDataLoaders.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.load(ConfigDataImporter.java:128)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:86)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:121)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processInitial(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:240)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:227)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:102)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:374)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:332)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
        at com.classpath.ordersapi.OrdersApiApplication.main(OrdersApiApplication.java:13)
11:23:01.735 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter -

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader.createYaml(OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:69)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions.setMaxAliasesForCollections(int)'

The method's class, org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/app/lib/snakeyaml-1.23-android.jar!/org/yaml/snakeyaml/LoaderOptions.class
    jar:file:/app/lib/snakeyaml-1.28.jar!/org/yaml/snakeyaml/LoaderOptions.class
The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:
    org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions: file:/app/lib/snakeyaml-1.23-android.jar

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker/issues/733

Thanks for reporting this issue, and yes, there's a few issues with this library, the incompatibility with Spring Boot is one of them. That's why we created a port of this library, which does work with spring boot. You can find it at https://www.datafaker.net, and requires only minimal code changes to get it up and running, only the package name changed (plus we have many improvements, no security issues, etc)